# chromedriver building from source not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am on Mac (OSX-13.13) , I am following the instructions here.

- https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/mac_build_instructions.md

args config is:

```
`is_debug = false`

`is_component_build = true`

`symbol_level = 0`
```

The ninja command is:

```
`autoninja -C out/Default chrome/test/chromedriver:chromedriver`
```

- Then copied the newly built chrome driver found at
  `out/Default/chromedriver` out to directory where selenium uses it ie

  `cp out/Default/chromedriver chromedriver_modified`
- Then using it in python like this:

  `driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=some_chrome_options, executable_path='path/to/chromedriver_modified')`

  > selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service
  >   /Users/ishandutta2007/Downloads/chromedriver_modified unexpectedly
  >   exited. Status code was: -6

PS: Interestingly this built is only 5MB, where as the standard one which is downloaded from [here](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) is 11MB

Comment: @corey-goldberg can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out myself, basically I had set `is_component_build = false` which is why the binary is split into one chromedriver and several other dylibs. Those dylibs will also have to be copied to the same folder which explain why it was small. To get it correct either the path containing dromedriver with all libs has to be given or recompiled with `is_component_build = false` to get a single large executable

Comment: The solution worked for me as well and we need to set "is_component_build = false" to get the chromedriver packaged with all the dependencies. Thank you